# Trying to make a basic haskell program

Tags: haskell, programming-languages, interpreter

I'm trying to make some haskell code to determine whether a string is either even or odd.

```
even l evaluates to S 0 if l is a list of even length and evaluates to 0 if l is not of even length, for example

even a1:a2:a3:a4:#      --->   S 0    
even a1:a2:a3:a4:a5:#   --->   0
```

I'm not sure where to go and any help would be greatly appreciated. The interpreter looks like this

```
execCBN :: Program -> Exp
execCBN (Prog e) = evalCBN e

evalCBN :: Exp -> Exp
evalCBN (EApp e1 e2) = case (evalCBN e1) of
    (EAbs i e1') -> evalCBN (subst i e2 e1')
    e1' -> EApp e1' e2
evalCBN (EIf e1 e2 e3 e4) = if (evalCBN e1) == (evalCBN e2) then evalCBN e3 else evalCBN e4
evalCBN (ELet i e1 e2) = evalCBN (EApp (EAbs i e2) e1) 
evalCBN (ERec i e1 e2) = evalCBN (EApp (EAbs i e2) (EFix (EAbs i e1)))
evalCBN (EFix e) = evalCBN (EApp e (EFix e)) 
evalCBN (EMinusOne e) = case (evalCBN e) of
    ENat0 -> ENat0
    (ENatS e) -> e
evalCBN (ENatS e') = ENatS (evalCBN e')
evalCBN x = x
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically about this do you need help with?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I haven't been able to really figure anything out but I was told "For example, the function plus can be described by the equations

plus 0 y = y
plus (S x) y = S (plus x y)"

Comment: Are you sure this is Haskell? In Haskell, `[]` means the empty list, not `#`.

Comment: @JosephSible to be honest I'm not sure. I added some more info above

Comment: I imagine you are looking for something like this: `even []           = True;
even [a]         = False;
even (a:b:xs) = True && even xs;`

Comment: I think the `S` and `S 0` is probably some Peano number encoding.

Comment: What does the `CBN` in `execCBN` stand for? It seems like you don't need a Haskell program, but a program written in a language you have an interpreter for. If you add more information about that in your question, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Bill: I think people are eager to answer if you supply enough information. It seems that you're not building a Haskell function that checks if a Haskell list has an even number of elements, but rather an interpreter for a simple lambda calculus in which lists are Peano encoded. Please specify this if it's the case, so that people don't answer a question you didn't ask.

Comment: @SimonShine Ya I am building a an interpreter for a simple lambda calculus equation

Comment: @Garrison CBN stand for call by need. It's written in a haskell file so I'm not 100% sure if it's in haskell or something else

Answer (score 0):

First, here are some suggestions to improve on your future Q&As on StackOverflow:

- Make sure your question contains a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your example code leaves out parts that are necessary to run or even understand what's going on.
- Provide enough context to make the question understandable: Having "CBN" in the code wasn't enough for every commenter to understand what was going on. It took some effort for me to figure out that what you meant was "inside this lambda evaluator", and even then "whether a string is either even or odd" is still not completely obvious: What's a string? Do you mean to encode character string literals using Peano numbers, or do you mean "whether a Peano-encoded *natural number* is even or odd"?
- If you don't provide enough context, you make the question immensely hard to answer, because the answerer will either have to go out of their way and recreate a part of your situation, provide multiple answers for each possible interpretation, or make a random guess.

---

Second, here is my interpretation of what you're asking:

> Given the following lambda calculus interpreter, how would I construct an `Exp` that represents a function that returns if a Peano-encoded natural number is even or odd? That is, if my `even :: Exp` is an `EAbs "x" ...`, then
>
> ```
> eval (EApp even zero)  `shouldBe` true
> eval (EApp even one)   `shouldBe` false
> eval (EApp even two)   `shouldBe` true
> eval (EApp even three) `shouldBe` false
> eval (EApp even four)  `shouldBe` true
> where
>   zero = ENat0
>   one = ENatS zero
>   two = ENatS one
>   three = ENatS two
>   four = ENatS three
>   true = one
>   false = zero
> ```
>
> What would go into `even = EAbs "x" ...`?

And third, if I were to answer that question, I'd say:

You can do that in a number of ways, but since your lambda calculus has `Fix` and `Rec`, it would make sense to try and express recursion through them. You might start off by wondering how it's made in Haskell, then abstract out recursion, and then convert it to your lambda calculus interpreter.

With that approach, you might have:

```hs
even :: Int -> Int
even 0 = 1
even 1 = 0
even n = even (n - 2)
```

[Abstracting out recursion](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Fix_and_recursion#Recursion), you might get:

```hs
even :: Int -> Int
even = fix (\rec n ->
  if n == 0 then 1 else
  if n == 1 then 0 else
  rec (n - 2))
```

I'll leave the rest for you to express using terms from your syntax tree.